# Adding objects to a dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, dictionary, firebase

I am trying to add 2 objects to a dictionary before sending it to a Post class for a photo feed.  This is what I have, I am using firebase.

```
if let postDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

         for(name, value) in postDict {
             if name == "postedBy" {

                 DataService.ds.REF_USERS.child(value as! String).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (friendDictionary) in

                     let userDict = friendDictionary.value as! NSDictionary
                     value.setValue(userDict.objectForKey("username"), forKey: "username")
                     value.setValue(userDict.objectForKey("profileThumbUrl"), forKey: "profileThumbUrl")
                     self.collectionView?.reloadData()

                 })
             }
         }

         let key = snap.key
         let post = Post(postKey: key, dictionary: postDict)
         self.posts.append(post)
```

The problem with this is that when I try to user setValue() to add username and profileThumbUrl to value in postDict I get the error: "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key username."  I have used this type of method in other situations so I don't know if it's because i'm using "if let" at the beginning because I don't normally use that.  Any ideas?

Comment: What is the type for `value`?

Comment: Have you tried not using the if let?

Comment: I think value is anyobject

Comment: Yeah it's not the if let thing.  I still can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

objectForKey returns an optional type, which is not compliant for an NSDictionary, so you need to unwrap the optional for this to work.

Eg

```
for(name, value) in postDict {
         if name == "postedBy" {

             DataService.ds.REF_USERS.child(value as! String).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (friendDictionary) in

                 let userDict = friendDictionary.value as! NSDictionary

                 guard let username = userDict.objectForKey("username") else { continue }
                 guard let profileThumbURL = userDict.objectForKey("profileThumbUrl") else { continue }

                 value.setValue(username, forKey: "username")
                 value.setValue(profileThumbUrl, forKey: "profileThumbUrl")
                 self.collectionView?.reloadData()

             })
         }
     }
```